# Does anyone even notice poor antialiasing?

Tags: css, antialiasing

So I had a project where I used the CSS3 rotate, and the borders on things don't antialias very well. However nobody I showed it to noticed, only me. How many people actually notice poor antialiasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies; some people are highly sensitive to it, others not so much.  It also depends on the exact characteristics of the physical display, since antialiasing is dependent on the exact configuration of the red, green, and blue dots in a pixel.

Answer (score 3):

I notice - it really annoys me. Another thing I remember back from my game development days - many don't notice the aliasing specifically, but they do have a poorer impression of a game if it doesn't do it. So it has a subconscious impact.

Comment: Interesting. So they know there is something wrong, they just don't know what?

Comment: @zeel: that is actually quite common, and not just in computing — the feeling that something is subtly "off", but you can't put your finger on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Did you show them in your machine or shared a link?

Because that depends on browser and configuration. Some browsers support hardware acceleration, but not all graphic cards are supported, so may fall back to software render. In this case, may be less anti-aliased to save processing power.

Comment: My machine. I instantly noticed it, but no one else could see it.

Comment: it may not be the answer for the OP, but the point is well made nonetheless - the different browsers on the market can produce very different results when it comes to anti-aliasing, even with the same hardware. Different graphics hardware will also have a big effect, and even different monitors.

Comment: Yes I did find some computers displayed the page with almost perfect antialiasing, and others none at all.